# Parameterizing Jobs by Slaves

Tags: hudson, jenkins

I'd like to create a job to do some housekeeping on Jenkins slaves and trigger it manually whenever needed. I'd like to provide that job with a parameter to tell it on which slave to run. What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Jenkins 1.417 or newer, you can use the [Node Label Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin).

This lets you add a parameter to your build, identifying where it should be run.

Comment: You are the best! I do not have time to check it now, but will give it a shot on Sunday.

Comment: It worked. There is a [minor glitch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9348063/1178189), though.